# (...)when his elbow got injured or he got his elbow injured?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Rohan had been playing for his club for fifteen years when *his elbow got injured*.

Someone suggested to me that the italicized part of above sentence is wrong, the reason being the subject of *got* verb in above sentence - *his elbow* is wrong either the subject should be *he* i.e. *he got his elbow injured*  or *his elbow* should be used in passive form i.e. *his elbow was injured.* I don't understand why the subject *his elbow* is wrong?

Comment: The original sentence sounds fine to me, although _got injured_ sounds a little on the informal side.

Comment: Estimated hits from Google Books - [my leg got injured](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+leg+got+injured%22):29, [my leg was injured](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+leg+was+injured%22):895, [I injured my leg](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+injured+my+leg%22):830. There's safety in numbers, so you should look to the second and third alternatives there for guidance. Note that the first and second are semantically "passive" (***I*** didn't do anything, it was my ***leg*** which experienced (caused?) the fracture (***got*** can imply "volition").

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is definitely not wrong.

His elbow got injured.

It's fine. The suggestion `He got his elbow injured` is also fine, but it implies he had some part in getting it injured (through carelessness for example). Like this:

> He got arrested

means this arrest happened to him. (This is parallel to your example - not technically a passive but something that's semantically and structurally similar to a passive).

> He got himself arrested

This one's also technically not a passive. I would say this if I wanted to suggest he could have avoided the arrest (for example by not committing the crime or doing it more carefully).

[An excellent, and unusually truthful, video series about the passives in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcbHKbvwCnU&index=1&list=PLNRhI4Cc_QmsihIjUtqro3uBkGG3BC6dk). The nature of the get passive is described near the end of video 2.